# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^z}$ converges absolutely and uniformly

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{C}$. Assume that
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^z}$ converges absolutely for some 
>   $z= z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$. Prove that the series converges absolutely
>   and uniformly on $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \text{Re} z \ge \text{Re} z_0 \}$

This is another revision question I am working on. Here is how I have approached this question, would greatly appreciate any feedback if I have done anything wrong.

We are given that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^{z_0}}$$ converges absolutely. Then letting $z_0 = a+bi$, I have that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ||\frac{a_n}{n^a\cdot n^{bi}}||$$ converges. So it follows that

$$||\frac{a_n}{n^a\cdot n^{bi}}|| \le ||\frac{a_n}{n^a}||$$ Then if $z_0 = a'+b'i$ with $ a' \ge a$, it follows that

$$||\frac{a_n}{n^{a'}\cdot n^{b'i}}|| \le||\frac{a_n}{n^{a'}}||\le ||\frac{a_n}{n^a}||$$

Then since  $\frac{a_n}{n^a} \rightarrow 0 $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, by the Weierstrass-M Test, we have that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^z}$ converges absolutely and uniformly for $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \text{Re} z \ge \text{Re} z_0\}$

Would this be correct? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. Only more precisely: $|n^{ib}|=1$.

Comment: Thanks. Why is that equal to 1?

Comment: You're last sentence is weird : why do you say since $\frac{a_n}{n^a} \rightarrow 0$ ? Weierstrass-M Test do not need that.

Comment: @Fabien - But it does need that it converges right? I guess I am showing that it converges. And it does go to $0$ doesn't it?

Comment: It's not because $\frac{a_n}{n^a} \rightarrow 0$ that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^z}$ converge. For instance, take $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ but $\sum \frac{1}{n}\to \infty$

Comment: Uniform convergence: $|S_{\omega}(z)-S_{n}(z)| \leq S_{\omega}(Re(z_{0}))-S_{n}(Re(z_{0}))\longrightarrow 0$ for all $n$ and all $z$ with $Re(z)\geq Re(z_{0})$. Thus the rate of convergence is uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you need to change
**First**
$$|n^{ib}|=|\exp{i\cdot b\cdot ln(n)}|=|cos(b\cdot ln(n))+i\sin(b\cdot ln(n))|=\sqrt{cos(b\cdot ln(n))^2+sin(b\cdot ln(n))^2}=1$$

**Second**
You need to say $|a_n|\geq a_n$ and $|n^z|= n^a$ so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^{\alpha}}$ converge uniformly on $]z_o,\infty[$

**Third**
Just forget "since $\frac{a_n}{n^a} \rightarrow 0$" and write :
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^{\alpha}}$ converge so by the Weierstrass-M Test, we have that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^{\alpha '}}$ converges

and you can conclude !

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that $|n^z| = |n^a|$ in your Second part?

Comment: Sorry, stupid question, but how do you go from $|\exp{i\cdot b\cdot ln(n)}|$ to $\sqrt{cos(b\cdot ln(n))^2+sin(b\cdot ln(n))^2}$?

Comment: Thanks for your patience :). I got it.

Comment: Concluding that $|n^{ib}| = 1$, can I just say that: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ||\frac{a_n}{n^a\cdot n^{bi}}|| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ||\frac{a_n}{n^a}||$$ Or do you think I need to say $$||\frac{a_n}{n^a\cdot n^{bi}}|| = \frac{|a_n|}{|n^a|\cdot |n^{bi}|} = \frac{|a_n|}{|n^a|\cdot 1}$$. Thanks again.

Comment: The second one is better to show (I guess your teacher) that you understood why the imaginary part doesn't matter

Comment: Got you. Thanks very much.

Comment: Another thought as well, do I really need your second part? It's already given that $z_0$ converges uniformly and absolutely?

Comment: My second part is to explain your last equation so if you have explained your last equation, you don't need my second part ;)